# Powershell folder creation script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have about 1000 folders that I need to put subfolders in.

In each one of those folders I need to create these 3 identical folders

```
Contracts
Leases
General
```

Is there a way to tell powershell to look at each folder, and then put in those subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
#Get your directories
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory

#Loop through folders and make the subdirectories
$folders | ForEach-Object {
mkdir "$($_.FullName)\Contracts"
mkdir "$($_.FullName)\Leases"
mkdir "$($_.FullName)\General"
}
```